# How to send request to url that is set to 'login:admin' in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In my app.yaml, a url is defined to be:

```
- url: /api/.*
  script: main.app
  login: admin
  secure: always
```

I tried to the following code to talk to the api

```
import requests

def main():
    r = requests.get("https://test.appspots.com/api/get_data", auth=('me@me.com', 'password'))
    print r.status_code, r.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But authentication has failed and, judging from the output, I am redirect to a login page.

How can I use python to authenticate and access the url?

Comment: I think I would use a secret key and pass that in requests instead of using Google authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`login: admin` instructs Google App Engine to restrict URLs matching the given pattern to users who are authenticated with Google *AND* are Administrators of your Google App Engine project. There is no way to use standard HTTP Basic Authentication with this restriction. If you have a valid oAuth Bearer token you can pass it in the header in `requests.get` to handle the required authentication.

See this article on appidentity for some possible options:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/